# Fake internal calls of a SUT with FakeItEasy

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, fakeiteasy

I have a small C# class that handles printing.
I want to create (n)unit tests for this class, using
fakeItEasy. How can I fake the internal calls of this
class without faking the whole SUT ?

For example:

```
public class MyPrintHandler: IMyPrintHandler
{

    public MyPrintHandler(ILogger<MyPrintHandler> logger) 
    {
    }
         
    // function I want to (unit test
    public  async Task<bool> PrintAsync(string ipaddress)
    {
        try
        {               
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipaddress) )
            {
                return await StartPrint(ipaddress); // This cannot be called in a unit test, because it really start printing on a printer.
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {                                           
        }
        return false;

    }

    private  async Task<bool> StartPrint(string ipaddress)
    {
      // prints on the printer  
    }



[TestFixture]
public class MyPrintHandlerTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Succes_PrintAsync()
    {            
        using (var fake = new AutoFake())
        {
            // Arrange - configure the fake                   
            var sut = fake.Resolve<MyPrintHandler>();

            // Act
            await sut.PrintAsync("0.0.0.0"); // I want to prevent StartPrint() from being called..                                                 
        }       
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this, or is this not possible at all?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I would typically say that faking the SUT is an anti-pattern, to be avoided whenever possible, as it causes confusion. If you can refactor to introduce a collaborator that handles the `StartPrinting` method, I would strongly consider doing so. If this is not possible, you can try this, however

1. any method that you want to fake must be `virtual` or `abstract`, otherwise FakeItEasy cannot intercept it
2. any method that you want to fake must be `public` (or `internal`, if you can [grant dynamic proxy access](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/how-to-fake-internal-types/) to production code's internals)
3. you would then fake the SUT, specifying that it should [call the original (base) methods](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/calling-base-methods/), and finally
4. explicitly override the behaviour for the method that you want to intercept

Comment: thanks for the answer and for the alternative steps. I choosed to refactor and use an Adapter. But it is good to know what steps I could take in case it is necessary